# Android Calendar App Does Not Reliably Display Work Events

Tags: google-calendar

I use My Galaxy S5's Calendar App to display my personal (Gmail) and work calendar (Google Apps for work) entries but cannot rely on the accuracy of the Google Apps calendar entries.

I have no trouble receiving emails from both personal and work accounts using the Galaxy S5's Mail App and have configured the Calendar App's settings to display both my personal and work accounts' calendars.

What is the best way to configure the Android Calendar App to reliable sync with, and display my work events?

Comment: Please post more details regarding what your work email is (MS Exchange? Google Apps for Business?) As well as some screen shots of how your app is currently configured.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I've edit the original post to answer them.

Comment: Any updates on this issue?